# How can C allocate memory without an OS? (Cases where OS is written in C)

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, embedded

I am following a course where we are writing an OS on a microcontroller.

The OS is written in C and the instructor initializes stack spaces for each thread in the following way.

`int32_t TCB_STACK[NUM_OF_THREADS][STACK_SIZE];`

How can the memory be allocated **if there isn't any OS already running to service this in the first place?** Am I missing something?

Comment: Most OS is written in C or a similar low level language. The C code is simply compiled without making system calls to the OS and static (no external library). The code runs on one core at first and calls into several assembly files linked to the code to set up the processor and the OS. The code sets up the interrupt table (including exceptions) and the syscall handler. From there, the OS leaves every core to user mode threads and waits that one of its interrupt/exception/syscall handler is called. These include timers, external devices and CPU exceptions that a user mode thread triggered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to "allocate" anything as such on a bare metal system, you have full access to all of the physical memory and there's no one else to share it with.

On such a system those arrays end up in statically allocated RAM memory known as `.bss`. Where `.bss` is located and how large it is, is determined by the linker script. The linker script decides which parts of the memory to reserve for what. Stack, `.bss`, `.data` and so on. Similarly the flash memory for the actual program may be divided in several parts.